# String Contains checking - Java

Tags: java

```
String s1 = "6970596 (A1)";
String s2 = "6970596A1";
if (s1.contains(s2)) {
    System.out.println("value matched");
}
```

while execute the above, contains produce an False

my expectation it become an true, so how can i change my if conditions, at the same time below condition become an true

```
String s1 = "6970596 (A1)";
String s2 = "6970596";
if (s1.contains(s2)) {
    System.out.println("value matched");
}
```

please help me how will frame the if condition

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: if condition must have an true with both values

Comment: @OliCharlesworth He want's `s1.contains(s2)` to be `true`.

Comment: You are trying to **compare** two strings by checking if one is **entirely contained** inside the other. `.compareTo` and `.equals` do a better job of comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as if you want to ignore whitespace and the parenthesis in the first string.  You can replace these characters for the comparison.

```
public class IfCondition {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "6970596 (A1)";
        String s2 = "6970596A1";

        if (s1.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "").contains(s2)) {
            System.out.println("value matched");
        }
    }
}
```

In your example the `compare` method is working as expected since it does not find an exact match for the String s2 within the String s1.  In the [String#compare JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) it states `Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.`  The language cannot assume that you would like to ignore the whitespace and parens within the first String, therefore you must manipulate the string for your comparison.

Comment: But this will be true even for `s1 = "6970596 (A3)"`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thats not true.  I just tested.  Did you miss the negation of the character set `^`?

Comment: You are right. +1. I didn't notice the `^` :)

Comment: Your strings and the string the asker is using are different, he does not have A1 on the end of the second string.  Have you tested it using the same inputs?

Comment: @PaulBrindley: It seems the OP has since edited the question to make it incomprehensible.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I see it's listed as edited by someone else, not a well done edit I'll admit.